# Can an HTTP request to an HTTPS server be forced to encrypt?

Tags: ubuntu, https, http, apache2, node.js

I have an Unbuntu server running NodeJS, where I want to upload some files. Some of the files contain some data that I would prefer would not to be leaked, but it wouldn't be a massive issue if someone got a hold of the files. My NodeJS server is currently a plain HTTP server, but from what I understand from [this article](https://medium.com/@nileshsingh/everything-about-creating-an-https-server-using-node-js-2fc5c48a8d4e), it should be possible to force HTTP file uploads to be encrypted. Does that mean I can upload a file using an HTTP POST request, and it's encrypted? How does the file upload know to encrypt the file?

The HTTP request is sent from Microsoft Flow.

Comment: the moment serverfault became stackexchange :)

Comment: "How does the file upload know to encrypt the file?" All HTTPS links are "encrypted" because they use TLS. But you need to be careful about authentication, that is certificates. Otherwise you encrypt towards an unknown endpoint which is basically the same as being in the clear...

Answer (score 2):

HTTP protocol works on top of TCP protocol. HTTPS works on top of TLS. so underlying connections are different. In order to submit your form with HTTPS encryption you would need to upgrade your HTTP connection to HTTPS using "Upgrade" HTTP header. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/1.1_Upgrade_header

HTTP was not designed to encrypt data.

Regarding your nodejs question, lets look at the code snippet here

```js
var https = require('https');
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Module `https` will create a server that is listening on 443 port, which is used for your HTTPS traffic. next snippet creates your HTTP server which listens for traffic on port 80

```js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

So now, you have two servers listening on two different ports. To conclude my answer, HTTP and HTTPS are used on different connections. you cannot mutate your HTTP session in to HTTPS on the fly I am afraid.

Comment: See also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security

Comment: I'm using microsoft flow to send the HTTP request, so I believe I will just have to leave it unencrypted.

Comment: "you cannot mutate your HTTP session in to HTTPS on the fly I am afraid."  which is the contrary to what you state at the beginning with HTTP Upgrade (even if not really used in the wild)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek hm i didnt know about it :) thankfor the link

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution could be to set the `action` to the https url.

```
<form action="https://<YOUR_Server/post-handler" method="post" ...>
```

Comment: the moment server fault became stackexchange :)